# Trying to make a thumbnail of a youtube video and have it enlarge when clicked

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

Is there a way to make a thumbnail of a youtube video embedded into my html and when clicked, it enlarges to full size?  This way, I could have a row of video thumbnails, which is what I'm trying to do.

For instance, http://www.youtube.com/embed/Jxsl5DZtdcg?wmode=opaque ..... is one of my videos I'd like to put into a thumbnail, but I'm unsure how to do this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youtube already creates 4 thumbnails for every video, you can access them by the following format:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<youtube-id>/0.jpg 480x360
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<youtube-id>/1.jpg 120x90
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<youtube-id>/2.jpg 120x90
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<youtube-id>/3.jpg 120x90
```

So for your video it will be:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/Jxsl5DZtdcg/0.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/Jxsl5DZtdcg/1.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/Jxsl5DZtdcg/2.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/Jxsl5DZtdcg/3.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks Erwin!  To make it so when the client clicks it, the full size video appears, say, above the thumbnail, I would just to an <a href type of thing?  I really appreciate you taking the time to respond!